Gmail blacks out if you scroll the message
My mother has a relatively new (2-3 months) Samsung Tab S9 FE tablet.  It has developed a problem where if she attempts to scroll through the body of an email in Gmail, the body will blank out, as shown here:

This happens whether scrolling with finger or stylus.  If scrolling with the stylus, the small animated blue circle does appear even in the blacked out area.  Scrolling back and forth will cause the email body to reappear, usually only very briefly.  If I go back to the message list, then re-open an email, it appears normally again until the finger or stylus are used on the message body.
The non-body parts of the screen (header, time banner up top) still show during the email body disappearance.
If you click through a link in the email and open a browser, it displays normally even when scrolling.  Moving through the desktop (e.g. flipping between screens or bringing up the list of applications) all works with scrolling activity.
What I've done: I turned off dark mode in the gmail message settings.  I went into Settings -> Display and toggled every setting back, reproduced the behavior, and forth.  Things like light mode/dark mode, refresh rate, and Vivid colors.  None of those settings made any difference.
Device details: Device is a Galaxy Tab S9 FE, model SM-X510. One UI version 6.1.1, Android version 14, security patch level 10/1/2024.  Current version X510XXS6BXJ1/X510OXM6BXJ1

Could be a problem with the HTML rederer, most likely the email is shown in a WebView. You can enable developer options to see what app is used for providing WebView.  Usually on Android 14 this should be the invisible app Android System WebView. Make sure this app is updated to it's latest state.

I verified that Android System WebView was the HTML renderer and that it was up to date.  I also tried clearing its cache and disk.  No luck, but thank you for the idea.

After trying all suggestions here tried the following steps:

Backup the device config to Samsung's 30-day cloud
Reset the device to factory defaults
Sync basic settings from her cell phone (wireless, Gmail at least)
Test Gmail (the problem disappeared)
Restore the device from Samsung's 30-day cloud
Test Gmail (the problem still disappeared)

So the factory reset seems efficacious but I'll probably keep my fingers crossed for a while.

It seems to me that you are selecting the image instead of scrolling.  Don't rest your finger and then scroll.  Scroll as soon as your finger touches the screen.
If this is not the case then take into where you purchased it from.

The problem was not selecting - the image above is a looping gif, it gives up a lot of detail :) and I also tested on multiple emails, some without images.
